# Broken WSUS - can't download updates

Tags: windows, windows-update, windows-server-2012, wsus

I’m really struggling to get my WSUS server to work after moving from a Server 2008 box. Any suggestions would be deeply appreciated.

This is a project which I have had to put on hold for the last week or two, but due to the feature updates from Windows 10 I would like to push forward and iron out these issues.

**What I’ve done**

1. Deployed WSUS roles on server 2012
2. Configured WSUS exactly the same as our previous system
3. Resolved an issue with NETWORK SERVICE permissions within the WSUS content drive
4. Resolved an update file download issue by changing the port from 8530 to 80
5. Identified that all client updates fail since the port change was made
6. Removed WSUS server role and reinstalled *(Maybe I should cleanly install the server??)*
   I do not have the permission to re-deploy the server until my supervisor returns.
7. Re-installed WSUS, reconfigured, left on port 8530
   Installed all applicable Windows updates 
   Manual steps completed:
8. Open an elevated Command Prompt window, and then run "C:\Program Files\Update Services\Tools\wsusutil.exe postinstall /servicing" (case sensitive, assume C: as the system volume).
9. Select HTTP Activation under .NET Framework 4.5 Features in the Server Manager Add Roles and Features wizard.
10. Restart the WSUS service.
    Still not working..

WSUS is not downloading updates - on the previous install all client updates failed when switching the port to 80.

**Here are my event logs:**

**Error 08/08/2016 14:41:20 Windows Server Update Services  12072   9**
The WSUS content directory is not accessible.
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.HealthMonitoring.HmtWebServices.CheckContentDirWebAccess(EventLoggingType type, HealthEventLogger logger)

**Error 08/08/2016 14:41:20 Windows Server Update Services  10032   7**
The server is failing to download some updates.

**Error 08/08/2016 14:41:20 Windows Server Update Services  13032   6**
Many client computers have not reported back to the server in the 
last 30 days. 64 have been detected so far.

**Error 08/08/2016 14:41:20 Windows Server Update Services  13002   6**
Client computers are installing updates with a higher than 25 percent 
failure rate. This is not normal.

**WSUS CONFIG**
•   Server 2012 R2 WSUS 6.3.9600.16384
•   Port: 8530 (rule to allow all connections set in firewall)
•   No proxy used, downloads updates from microsoft

**Screenshots:**

[image]

**Other Threads:**
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1758599-broken-wsus-2012-r2

Comment: Have you installed the wsus update through windows update?

Comment: Have you considered pushing the port number change, etc. for the clients via GPO; this is how the companies that use this technology I support do it and it works just fine? The clients don't check in with the WSUS server on port 80 though in these cases.

Comment: @LPChip Yes i did because the download failed from WSUS itself.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I am going to check over GPO settings and force an update tomorrow. But this isn't the  problem, downloads are sitting at 0/800MB!